# Why there is a time gap between the news presenter and the field reporter?

Tags: electromagnetism, everyday-life

This one has been in my mind for years, but I simply can not find any reason for this event.

**The Situation**

Imagine yourself sitting in the living room while watching television. It's 9 p.m and the news are on. Suddenly the news presenter announce of an event and contacts a field reporter, and start asking him questions or delivers us the exposition for the story.

**The Problem**

In these cases, most of the times, because that particular event is pretty far away from the studio, there is a time gap between the speech of the news reporter until it gets to the field reporter. Now, naturally you can think - well, thats make sence - the voice, usually travelling through some kind of electromagnetic force by using an antena or a satellite, takes time to travel long distances, thus creating this time gap between it's emerging from the studio and it's arrival to the reporter. And this is where I get to the point - When the field reporter answers back, and start talking, this time gap magically disappears, and you can see that his lips are synchronized with his voice.

**The Questions**

- Why is this happening?
- Both the studio and the reporter uses the same method to tranfer their voices? If not, why? If yes, why there is a time gap only in one direction?

I hope this question is physics related :)

Comment: Howsabout you estimate the total time gap, assuming any transfer path you like (ground wire, satellite link) and all data going the speed of light?

Comment: Because the video of the reporter's lips and the audio of his speech are tied together and any delay in transmission and relaying affects both the same.  Same reason you can watch a movie decades after it was made, but the audio is still in sync with the picture.  This really should be obvious.

Comment: I was watching such a newscast, and the field reporter actually was listening to a cell phone, and the microphone picked it up. So on the TV the anchor asked Question XYZ? and you could hear the Question XYZ? come from the field reporter's cell phone about a second later. So the field reporter would hear the question sooner if he simply watched the channel! I can guess why, but I really don't know.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey  more likely that's due to digital buffering than time of travel.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey "So the field reporter would hear the question sooner if he simply watched the channel!" .It is not necessarily true. Suppose anchor says XYZ at 12:00:00 and time required to reach the signal(XYZ) to reporter and  return back to the anchor is 1 second. Then anchor sees the signal(XYZ) come from the reporters cell phone at 12:00:01. But that does not necessarily mean you are also watching these at the same time. Maybe the signal takes 5 seconds,say, to reach you. so you are hearing anchor's question at 12:00:05 and the reporter's cell phone at 12:00:06.

Comment: @user22180: As I said, I can guess too. But guessing isn't knowing. Somebody knows the answer. I don't.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey, In that case it would be better to mention your guess in few words too so that everybody knows what **maybe** a possible answer.

Answer (score 4):

The field reporter's lips and voice appear synchronized because the reporter's image and sound are transmitted back to the studio using the same medium, so both are delayed by the same amount.

There is a time delay in both directions.  It appears that there is only a delay between when the news presenter speaks and when the field reporter speaks because you are only being shown the perspective of the news presenter.  If you were standing next to the field reporter, it would appear that the only delay is between when the field reporter speaks and when the news presenter speaks.

When the field reporter's response to a question appears delayed from the studio's perspective, only part of that delay is due to the delay between when the news presenter speaks and when the field reporter hears it.  The rest of that delay is due to the delay between when the reporter actually responds, and when the reporter's image and sound are received by the studio.

Comment: *the reporter's image and sound are transmitted back to the studio using the same medium* It seems unlikely to me that this is due to the propagation of electromagnetic signals. We don't notice any such propagation delay in a phone call, and the distances involved, even if it's going through a satellite, are too short to explain the delay. Propagation to a geosynchronous satellite is only about 0.1 s round-trip, which is much less than what we observe. And most communications satellites are in much lower orbits than that.